# jquery ui tab with points

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Any idea how i can get rid of the three dots that appear on this default jquery ui tab. I'm thinking its something to do with the css sheet, but i'm unsure which element to modify. Has anybody else seen this?

[image]

The code (all regular enough)

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="#prereg">Pre-registration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#results">Past Results</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="info">
        <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
        <pre><code>$('#example').tabs();</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="map">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="prereg">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="results">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as your full HTML and CSS for this page. Providing a link to a page with this issue is much more preferred.

Comment: Nothing here: http://jsbin.com/axuno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy
use this css

```
#tabs li{
 list-style-type: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: You'll want the ul element for list-style type, not the li element.

Comment: I'm using the YAML library for my layout, and i found 'list-style-type' in the content.css file, updating the YAML css fixed the issue. thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#tabs ul { list-style: none }
```

If it still is there, either trace what CSS rule is turning the `list-style` back on, or add `!important` after the word `none`

Answer (score 2):

More info about your css would be needed, but looking at what you have so far, adding this to your css sheet may work:

```
#tabs ul{list-style-type:none;}
```